Issue with ros2 jazzy and gazebo harmonic ros integration
I’m quite new wit ROS and gazebo and I have been having an issue for several days:
when following the tutorial : Spawn a Gazebo model from ROS 2 — Gazebo harmonic documentation
It doesn’t work, after trying many time to reinstall, I found out that I don’t have the needed files in /opt/ros/jazzy/share/ros_gz_sim/launch
looking at the github it seems the jazzy/harmonic branch doesn’t have those files ( ros_gz/ros_gz_sim/launch at jazzy · gazebosim/ros_gz · GitHub )
What should I do to be able to make it work ?
thanks

For some reason that launch file does indeed not exist in the package for ROS2 Jazzy; and frankly, I'm not sure why other than Jazzy being a new distro.
That said, the launch file does exist here on the main ros2 branch. As a stopgap until the repo maintainers update their branch the only real option is to copy that file directly to your install in /opt. Note that other dependencies might be missing, so I'd recommending searching for them on the main ros2 branch as well.
